# transactional method throwing "no transactional entityManager available"

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have a method that is defined as @transactional.  In fact I have a method calling a method that calls a method and all three are @transactional.  The transactional logic worked fine, until I pulled a few methods out into an abstract class for some code reuse, which appears to have broken my logic somehow.

The transactional method is from an abstract class, here is a partial snippet of the relevant parts (I have to rewrite this by hand so forgive me for typos):

```
public abstract class ReadWriteService<ReadEntityTempalte extends IEntity, WriteEntityTemplate extends IEntity>

//extends jpaRepository, created using @enableJpaRepositories
private searchRepository<WriteEntityTemplate, String> writeRepository;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@transactional
public ReadEntityTemplate save(final WriteEntityTemplate entity){

    if(entity == null) return null;

    WriteEntityTemplate returnValue = writeRepository_.save(entity);

    postSave(returnValue);  //checks our security logic 

    flush();

    ReadEntityTemplate returnEntity = find(returnValue.getId());

    //required to detect changes made to the view by our save
    em.refresh(returnEntity);

 }
```

It's written this way because we are using views so the return value may be modified in the find() to the view.  This logic worked in the past, and still works for a number of calls.

The method that fails is:

```
 @Override
 @transational

 public void configure(EntityFileConfig config) throws ClassNotFoundException{

     //load config from file

     for(EntityConfig entityConfig: entityConfigs){

        EntityType entityType=EntityTypeService_.find(entityConfig.getKey());

        if(entityType==null){
             entityType = EntityType.createByRequiredFields(entityConfig.getKey());
        }

         //update entityType to reflect config file.

       entityType = entityTypeService_.save(entityType);

       for(String permissionName: entityConfig.getPermissions()){
           if(!entityTypeService_.hasPermission(entityType, permissionName)){

              Permission permission = permissionSetup.getPermission(permissionName);

               if(permission!=null)
                  //fails on below lines
                  permissionService._.addPermission(entityType, permission);

                }
            }
       }
   }
```

both the entityTypeService and the permissionService extend the above abstract class and use the same save method without alteration, addPermissions is a forloop that calls save on each permission.

The entityTypeService works, but the permissionService fails.   When The permission service is called if I do em.isTransactionalEntity it returns false.

All @transactional annotations are using the spring annotation, not the javax one.

Actually, it seems as if a few of the permissions would save and others wouldn't, almost as if it's non-deterministic, but this may simple be due to modifying a database file that had some of the values already set and thus didn't need to run some of the logic the first time through.

I've done quite a bit of stumbling around but am no closer to determining what would cause my transaction to end.  I had thought perhaps it was the @persistenceContext, since the JPARepos get their entityManager through a different approach then autowireing with @persistenceContext, but if that were the case everything would fail?

Any help would be appreciated, I'm pretty stumped on the cause of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have enabled `@EnableTransactionManagement` on `@Configuration` class.

Since you didn't set any propagation on `@Transaction` the default value is `Required`. It means all methods must be part of transaction. Since one of your abstract methods is not part of the `@Transactional` hence the error.

[image]

[For more information on Spring Transactions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

Note: Image taken from above link.